# Ubuntu Build Package From Source

Tags: ubuntu, dpkg

I'm trying to build p7zip_16.02:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/p7zip/

for Ubuntu 15.10 and 16.04. I'm using the following guide:

http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/packaging-new-software.html

My issue is that the package that is built from the source is only installing the documentation and not the actual binaries. I know `make all` will build all of the binaries.

How can I build the package so that is uses `make all` instead of whatever it's running by default?

Comment: did you run `make` and `make install` before creating the package? from the documentation it appears that you are supposed to have.

Comment: the documentation requests that you make and make install to test the process not to package it. when i run the bzr command it builds an entirely new directory separate from the directory that i built initially